# How to get selected menu value using jQuery UI and jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to get menu value and set text to button?

http://jsfiddle.net/p576v/2/

```
 $("#test").click(function(){
        $( "#menu" ).show();
     $( "#menu" ).menu();

    });

    $("ul#menu li a ").click(function(e){
      alert("---")
         $( "#menu" ).hide();
    })
```

Comment: `jQuery` has just a single `r` - that's quite enough!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for selected value in text

```
$("#test").click(function(){
$( "#menu" ).show();
$( "#menu" ).menu();

});

$("ul#menu li a ").click(function(e){

 $( "#menu" ).hide();
$("#menuvalue").val(this.childNodes[0].data);

});
```

Refer this fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctErh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("ul#menu li a ").click(function(e){
    $("#test").text(e.currentTarget.innerText);
    $( "#menu" ).hide();
    console.log(e);
})
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pryszkie/99mLM/3/
(edited)